# making a dictionary from another dictionary by searching keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
 dictionary1={'orange':[red,yellow],'green':[blue,yellow],'purple'[red,blue]}
```

and want to make a new dictionary that takes the old one and turns it into something like:

```
dictionary2={'red':[orange,purple],'blue':[green,purple],'yellow':[orange,green]}
```

so basically the code should go through the values, and make each one a key with the old keys associated with them set as a value (sorry that wording's a bit confusing)

this is what I tried:

```
def makeReverseDictionary():
    dictionary1 ={}
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    dictionary2={}
    for k, v in dictionary1.iteritems():
        dictionary2.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
    print (dictionary2)
```

and I get `list objects are unhashable` as an error. I think what might be happening is that it is trying to assign each value as a key twice (eg. yellow,yellow:[orange,green]) which is impossible. But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: how does `'yellow'[orange,green]` come about?

Comment: what if you have two of the same values in a list and already have that key in the updated dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list objects are unhashable` error arises if you try and use a whole list as a key. You need to iterate through the list and use each item as a key.

```
dict1 = {'orange':['red','yellow'], 'green':['blue','yellow'], 'purple':['red','blue']}

dict2 = {}

for k,vlist in dict1.iteritems(): # or dict1.items() in Python3
    for v in vlist:
        dict2.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
```

This produces `dict2` as:

```
{'blue': ['purple', 'green'], 'yellow': ['orange', 'green'], 'red': ['orange', 'purple']}
```

*Edit:*

An alternative to `setdefault` would be to use a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for `dict2`.